# android: do something after playing audio file

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

i try to stream and play an audio file in my application. i use this code :

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.setDataSource(url);
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

i want to know is it possible to detect when player finished playing ? i want to change a button color after player finished playing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [`setOnCompletionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)) method:

```
player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Done playing!");
    }
});
```

You can actually set a ton of callbacks here. In addition to `setOnCompletionListener`, we have:

- `setOnBufferingUpdateListener`
- `setOnErrorListener`
- `setOnInfoListener`
- `setOnPreparedListener`
- `setOnSeekCompleteListener`
- `setOnTimedMetaDataAvailableListener`
- `setOnTimedTextListener`
- `setOnVideoSizeChangedListener`.